# Slippy map tiles from geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, mbtiles, maperitive

I found a lot of solutions how to provide nice map tiles from local store without call external APIs (google, osm, and so on...).

Possibility which I found:

1. data from PostGIS to Geoserver will be styled with SLD and render as
   tiles
2. store map tiles in image format in structured folders for different zoom levels.
3. store map tiles in mbtiles format and import it into Geoserver

**Which one is the best solution?** I try 2. and 3. option with Maperitive over command:

```
generate-tiles minzoom=10 maxzoom=17
```

into images and also into mbtiles, but label will be bad readable. Generated output will be in lower quality than maps which I can see in Maperitive.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to try the 1st option using shapefiles together with GeoWebCache. shapefiles in many situations perform better than PostGIS.

Comment: So should I download osm file of my required extract and split it into shape files?

Comment: Do you need area bigger than one country? just download the shapes of the country you need from here: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/
And there is sld for osm https://github.com/FlorentDotMe/archives/tree/master/2013.03.23-OSM-Styles-for-GeoServer   but I havent tried them yet.

Comment: This folder contains a lot of shp files. Should I import all of them? https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2017/01/27/7NjX.png

Comment: It depends what kind of data do you want to show on the map. If all, than yes - you need  all of them

Comment: this shape files not works for me ... when I add new data source in Geoserver, and choose some shp file Coordinate Reference Systems could not load Native SRS, it signed as UNKNOWN instead some code and could not load native bounds from this too.